# Autobiographies and correspondences of mathematicians

Tags: ho.history-overview, big-list

Lately I have enjoyed reading several **autobiographies** and **correspondences** of mathematicians. I'd like to find more, so I thought I'd ask here which others you have come across and enjoyed.

P.S. I have collected suggestions from answers to an earlier similar question [Autobiography of mathematicians](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102597/autobiography-of-mathematicians) and this one into the following list:

**Autobiographies**

(1) *Souvenirs d'apprentissage*, André Weil (In English: *Apprenticeship of a Mathematician*)

(2) *Récoltes et Semailles*, Alexander Grothendieck

(3) *Un mathématicien aux prises avec le siècle*, Laurent Schwartz (In English: *A Mathematician Grappling with His Century*)

(4) *The Map of My Life*, Goro Shimura

(5) *A Mathematician's Apology*, G. H. Hardy

(6) *Adventures of a Mathematician*, Stanislaw Ulam

(7) *I Am a Mathematician*, Norbert Wiener

(8) *Love and Math*, Edward Frenkel

(9) *I Want to Be a Mathematician: An Automathography in Three Parts*, Paul Halmos

(10) *Un mathématicien juif*, Häim Brezis

(11) *La forme d'une vie: Mémoires (1924-2010)*, Benoit Maldelbrot (In English: *The Fractalist: Memoir of a Scientific Maverick*)

(12) *Théorème Vivant*, Cédric Villani (In English: *Birth of a Theorem: A Mathematical Adventure*)

(13) *To Talk of Many Things, An Autobiography*, Dame Kathleen Ollerenshaw

(14) *Will to Freedom*, Egon Balas

(15) *So hab ich's erlebt*, Walter Rudin (In English: *The Way I Remember It*)

(16) *Eine Frau und die Mathematik 1933--1940: der Beginn einer wissenschafltichen Laufbah*n, Helene Braun

(17) *Wspomnienia I zapiski*, Hugo Steinhaus (In German: *Erinnerungen und Aufzeichnungen*)

(18) *A Mathematical Autobiography*, Saunders Mac Lane

(19) *Random Curves: Journeys of a Mathematican*, Neal Koblitz

(20) *Enigmas of Chance: An Autobiography*, Marc Kac

(21) *Vospominanifa detstva*, Sofya Kovalevskaya (In English: *A Russian Childhood*)

(22) *De Vita propria*, Girolamo Cardano (In English: *The Book of My Life*)

(23) *Ex-Prodigy: My Childhood and Youth*, Norbert Wiener

(24) *Eye of the Hurricane*, Richard Bellman

(25) *Passages from the life of a philosopher*, Charles Babbage

(26) *Autobiography* of Sir George Biddell Airy

(27) *Schrijf dat op, Hans. Knipsels uit een leven*, Hans Freudenthal (In English: *Write that down, Hans. Excerpts from a life*)

(28) *A Half Century of Polish Mathematics: Remembrances and Reflections*, Kuratowski, Kazimierz

(29) *La mia vita di matematico attraverso la cronistoria dei miei lavori*, Francesco Giacomo Tricomi

(30) *Pushing limits : From West Point to Berkeley & Beyond*, Ted Hill

(31) *My Search for Ramanujan: How I Learned to Count*, Ken Ono and Amir D. Aczel

**Correspondence**

(1) Grothendieck-Serre Correspondence (AMS/SMF)

(2) Correspondance Serre-Tate (SMF)

(3) Ramanujan: Letters and Commentary (AMS)

Comment: Norbert Wiener also has a companion volume, "Ex-Prodigy".

Answer (score 3):

I think you will enjoy Norbert Wiener's autobiographic "I Am a Mathematician".

Comment: I think there's an 'a' in the title.  Do you know if either this or Halmos's *I want to be a mathematician* was named in response to the other?

Comment: Thanks, LSpice, corrected. I originally read it as a kid in Russian translation, where there are no articles, so I actually checked the Amazon page before posting. The title there has no article, but on the photo of the cover there is an "a", so this must be a typo on the Amazon page. I don't know whether this echo of Halmos is deliberate.

Comment: Amazon lists Wiener's as from 1964, and my copy of Halmos's is copyright 1985, so I guess the echoing would have to go the other way.

Answer (score 3):

Edward Frenkel's "Love and Math" is a mix of popular maths book, autobiography, and general declaration of love towards mathematics.

Comment: I think this was not mentioned in the earlier autobiography thread. Maybe you could add it there.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: done!

Answer (score 3):

Paul R. Halmos: [I Want to Be a Mathematician: An Automathography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883854457).

Benoit B. Maldelbrot: [La forme d'une vie: Mémoires (1924-2010)](https://www.amazon.fr/forme-dune-vie-M%C3%A9moires-1924-2010/dp/2081220369).

Cédric Villani: [Théorème vivant](https://www.amazon.fr/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me-vivant-C%C3%A9dric-Villani/dp/2253174904/ref=pd_sim_nf_14_1/257-3565410-8717448?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=2253174904&pd_rd_r=3c80a6e6-a6d1-4c42-aa91-f5ab2bd7c1da&pd_rd_w=GXLTQ&pd_rd_wg=ONtFX&pf_rd_p=989549ee-b4b9-468d-9113-731b03560554&pf_rd_r=YQA6WGMZDBMD7ZB2G0J1&psc=1&refRID=YQA6WGMZDBMD7ZB2G0J1).

Comment: I hardly dare suggest something about community norms to someone with 14 times my reputation, but I think that big-list tradition is to have one answer per post so that people can vote on them individually.  (In particular, I don't know the other books, but really want to upvote Halmos's.)

Comment: Oh I am sorry, in fact I rarely answer big lists questions, but I found this this one particularly interesting  :-) Should I split the answer in three?

Comment: I think that is the norm.  It'll be made CW eventually, so there is no difference in terms of 'unduly' earning triple reputation.

Comment: ok. Unfortunately the question is now closed, so adding new answers is not possible anymore. On this one, I will leave it like this.

Answer (score 3):

Haïm Brezis: *Un mathématicien juif*.

I don't know whether it has been translated in English.

Comment: I think this was not mentioned in the earlier autobiography thread. Maybe you could add it there.